# Error de conexión al hacer migrate

Tags: laravel, composer, artisan

Al ejecutar comando ***php artisan migrate*** devuelve el siguiente error. Entiendo que error de conexión. No comprendo dónde configuro mal la conexión. Añado capturas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si revisas la primer parte de tu error dice: **to open stream: Permission denied**, esto tiene que ver con permisos de escritura a dicha carpeta de migraciones

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de permisos, no de conexión a la base de datos, ejecuta los siguientes comandos en la terminal posicionándote en la raíz de tu proyecto.

```
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```